Cohen reals at limit steps in a finite support iteration
Without success, I have been trying to find who was the first to prove the folklore result that any finite support iteration of non-trivial posets adds Cohen reals at limits steps. Does anybody know?

But isn't this very easy once you understand the basic notions?

The idea is that, if you fix a (name for a) nontrivial condition $\dot p_n$ at stage $n$, then any dense set for Cohen-real forcing translates into a dense set of conditions in the forcing iteration, namely, the condition that exhibit the corresponding relation to these fixed $\dot p_n$. So the iteration generic will add a Cohen real by considering how it relates to those conditions.

@JoelDavidHamkins I'm not asking about the proof, but I want to know who this result is due to, or where it was proved the first time. I'm asking about the history.

Laver certainly understood this fact about finite support iterations when he wrote his paper on the Borel conjecture (1976). I just checked, though, and I can't see any hint in his paper of who first proved it.

Thank you @WillBrian for the information.
